# How to structure BEM modifiers with nested elements in SASS

Tags: html, css, sass, bem

SASS + BEM is pretty much a match made in heaven most of the time, but a common struggle of mine is understand how to best define BEM modifiers on an element that affects it's child elements while using SASS parent selectors.

I have the following component defined in SASS using BEM style syntax:

```
.card {
  background-color: #FFF;

  &__value {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

This works well because of SASS's parent selector. It keeps relevant code organized and self-contained.

But when I need to add a modifier that alters a child element using a parent selector, the idea quickly falls apart:

```
.card {
  padding: 2em;

  &__value {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
  }

  &--big {
    padding: 2.5em;

    &__value {          // Is this going to work?
      font-size: 3em;
    }
  }
}
```

Nope. It generates this:

```
.card {
  padding: 2em;
}
.card__value {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #000;
}
.card--big {
  padding: 2.5em;
}
.card--big__value {  // Wrong
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

It would make more sense to somehow get this selector:

```
.card--big .card__value {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

The reason for this, is so you can simply add a modifier to the top level element and have it affect any or all of the child elements.

I've tried a couple approaches:

### Use two structures

```
.card {
  padding: 2em;

  &__value {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
  }
}

.card--big {
  padding: 2.5em;

  &__value {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}
```

This works (especially in this simplified demonstration) but in a more complicated set of components with many modifiers this can be a potential pain to maintain and keep bug free. Also, it would nice to continue to use SASS parent selectors if possible.

### Use a variable for the element

```
.card {
  $component: &;  // Set the variable here

  padding: 2em;

  &__value {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
  }

  &--big {
    padding: 2.5em;

    #{$component}__value {  // Use it here
      font-size: 3em;
    }
  }
}
```

This works well. But it seems kind of silly to have to define the element as a variable. Maybe it's the only real way to do this... I'm not sure. Are there better options to how to structure this?

Comment: Good point! This is the cleanest way of nesting rather than using a hundred mixins. I consider your question as self answered.

Comment: It can be done with ONE character `&--big {` becomes `&--big & {`  - check my answer for details.  Hopefully useful for anyone stumbling onto this in the future

Answer (score 6):

Why not just do this?

```
.card {
  padding: 2em;

  &__value {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
  }

  &--big {
    padding: 2.5em;
  }

  &--big &__value {  
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's one of the possible solutions. Not ideal since you are repeating component class names, but it's not too bad.

Comment: True! I like your option with the variable too, very creative!

Answer (score 3):

You can split up the modifiers in a different structure, but nested within the `.card` selector, like this:

```
.card {
  padding: 2em;

  &__value {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
  }

  &--big {
    padding: 2.5em;
  }

  &--big &__value {
    padding: 2.5em;
  }
}
```

Which will in turn produce this:

```
.card {
  padding: 2em;
}
.card__value {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #000;
}
.card--big {
  padding: 2.5em;
}
.card--big .card__value {
  padding: 2.5em;
}
```

I think this is an almost perfect way, although its not perfectly nested
I hope this was a help!

Answer (score 3):

I just found a much better way to achieve this with sass, by using a variable to store the value of the parent selector you can use it at any level of nesting!

For example here I am storing the `.card` selector in the $this variable, and reusing it like this `#{$this}`

So this code

```
.card {
  padding: 2em;

  &__value {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
  }
  $this: &;

  &--big {
    padding: 2.5em;

    #{$this}__value {
      font-size: 3em;
    }
  }
}
```

will compile to

```
.card {
  padding: 2em;
}
.card__value {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #000;
}
.card--big {
  padding: 2.5em;
}
.card--big .card__value {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

This answer was inspired by this article on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/caching-current-selector-sass/). Thanks to [Sergey Kovalenko](https://github.com/kvlsrg)

Comment: Thank you but this is exactly what I suggested in the question.

Comment: I see you are right, I saw your question when you asked it a while ago and now I came across this article so I just posted it

Answer (score 3):

There is another pattern you could use here.

This will:
 - separate actual card modifier from its elements' modifiers
 - will keep the modified styles within the same elements' selector so you don't need to scroll your code up and down to see what is being modified
 - will prevent more specific rules from appearing above less specific rules, if that's your thing

Here's an example:

```
// scss
.card {
  $component: &;

  padding: 2em;

  &--big {
    padding: 2.5em;
  }

  &__value {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;

    #{$component}--big & {
      font-size: 3em;
    }
  }
}

/* css */
.card {
  padding: 2em;
}
.card--big {
  padding: 2.5em;
}
.card__value {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #000;
}
.card--big .card__value {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding ONE character, no variables or mixins are needed.

`&--big {` becomes `&--big & {`:

```
.card {
  padding: 2em;

  &__value {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
  }

  &--big & {
    padding: 2.5em;

    &__value {          // Is this going to work? (yes!)
      font-size: 3em;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that result in `.card--big .card__value` ?

Comment: @JakeWilson I thought that's what the question is asking for

Answer (score 1):

Going through the same issue I've build a library called [Superbem](https://github.com/pittkost/superbem) which is basically a set of SCSS mixins that help you write BEM declarative way. Take a look:

```
@include block(card) {
    padding: 2em;

    @include element(value) {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: #000;
    }

    @include modifier(big) {
        padding: 2.5em;

        @include element(value) {
            font-size: 3em;
        }
    }
}
```

Gives you:

```
.card, .card--big {
    padding: 2em; 
}

.card__value {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000; 
}

.card--big {
    padding: 2.5em; 
}

.card--big .card__value {
    font-size: 3em; 
}
```

Hope you'll find this useful!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks quite fine but you may also try [@at-root](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root).

Comment: To what exactly? I don't see why `@at-root` can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
.card {
  padding: 2em;

  &__value {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
  }

  &--big {
    padding: 2.5em;

    &__value {          // Is this going to work?
      font-size: 3em;
    }
  }
}
```

You can achieve the result You wanted by the following :

```
.card {
  padding: 2em;

  &__value {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
  }

  &--big {
    padding: 2.5em;

    .card {
       &__value {          // this would work
          font-size: 3em;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It does but it gets away from using the parent selector. It's nice to use it as much as possible.